# Full Calender displaying military time

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar, date-formatting, fullcalendar-4

I am trying to find a way to remove the colon from the times in full calendar. For example I want to time to display like 1400 and not 14:00.

The code I have used so far work for converting to 24 hour time with a leading zero but I can find a way to get rid of the colon.

```
slotLabelFormat: {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    hour12: false
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that FullCalendar has native support for this, but it supports adding datetime library plugins. If you add moment.js as a plugin you can set up your calendar with a formatting string, something like this:

```
import momentPlugin from '@fullcalendar/moment';

const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [momentPlugin],
    slotLabelFormat: 'HHmm'
});
```

The 'HHmm' formatting string will give you a padded 24-hour hour and a padded minute, and as there is no colon between them, you have your military time. Take a look at their docs for using [momentjs plugin](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/moment-plugins) as well as Moment's own docs on [formatting strings](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/).

If you prefer a different plugin, they have another option (Luxon) listed [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting)